What are the system of equations for a quartic polynomial with only 3 distinct roots
If the system of equations for a quartic polynomial $$f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$$ with $4$ distinct roots: $p, q, r, s$ are:
$p + q + r + s = -b/a$ 
$pq + pr + ps + qr + qs + rs = c/a$ 
$pqr + pqs + prs + qrs = -d/a$ 
pqrs = e/a 
Then what are the system of equations for f(x) with 3 or 2 or 1 distinct root(s)

The equations you gave do not require $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ to be distinct.

I am assuming that you want all the roots real in your case.
For $3$ distinct roots
$k(x-a)^2(x-b)(x-c)=0$
For $2$ distinct roots
$k(x-a)^3(x-b)=0$
or
$k(x-a)^2(x-b)^2=0$
For $1$ distinct root
$k(x-a)^4=0$

In all these cases, it is assumed that $a\ne b\ne c$
